# issue with 'this' self-types and generic function in Typescript 2.4+

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance

I have a `BaseModel` which has CRUD methods like `save`. Business models can extend from BaseModel and just use `.save()` and its friends for free.

I've declared `save` with a return type of `Promise<this>` so when an instance of `RandomModel` calls `save` on itself, the return type is a very nice `Promise<RandomModel>` instead of the vague `Promise<BaseModel>` as is the purpose of self-types.

Issue is when I try to override `save` in a model with special needs.  Instead of calling the inherited method at all, `SpecialNeedsModel` re-implements `save` with the same signature, still returning `Promise<this>` as it must.

The problem is with the inner helper function which both `save`s use. It won't type-check, insisting that the type argument to the helper, `this`, doesn't satisfy the constraint of `BaseModel`.

This code worked in Typescript 2.3 and earlier, and the returned type of the overridden `save` was a promise of the derived, as expected. But the compiler switch `--noStrictGenericChecks` does not make the error go away.

Am I just missing something, like perhaps accidentally re-declaring a new self-type?

```
function helperFn<T extends BaseModel>(model: T, args?: Object): Promise<T> {
    console.log("do stuff with", model, args);
    return Promise.resolve(model);
}

export class BaseModel {
    save(): Promise<this> {
        return helperFn<this>(this);
    }
}


export class RandomModel extends BaseModel {
}

var Rmodel = new RandomModel();
Rmodel.save().then(_ => console.log("RandomModel saved"));


export class SpecialNeedsModel extends BaseModel {

    save(): Promise<this> {
        return helperFn<this>(this, { m: "create" }); // ERROR on <this>
    }
}

var SNmodel = new SpecialNeedsModel();
SNmodel.save().then(_ => console.log("SpecialNeedsModel saved"));
```

Update: it does seem related to the return value of the helperFn. If I don't return helperFn's value in SpecialNeeds.save(), and I remove the explicit `<this>` on helperFn or change it to `<SpecialNeedsModel>`,  no compiler error is given. And explicit `as Promise<this>` is needed on the end.

I understand covariance/contravarience is flipped for return values vs parameters, but on a self-type I don't see why it would be a problem.  For self-types I would expect this to work even with invariance.

Comment: This feels like a TypeScript bug to me but I'm not sure.  You could change `helperFn<this>()` to `helperFn<this & BaseModel>()` to make the error go away but I don't know why it's happening.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17533 seems possibly relevant?